# How to do a search engine like the CNN with Google Custom Search?

Tags: search, search-engine, google-custom-search

I'm trying to do a Google Custom Search engine for my website but the code that google provides is fully AJAX code.

To understand what I want go to http://www.cnn.com and find anything you want, then the results will be showed in another page.

How can I do something like that?

I'm trying using the JS files in that web but I'm "STACKOVERFLOWED!"

Answer (score 0):

When you get a google search form, they ask you in what page you want to show result. Try to fix this.